# Why do the ground state of baryons have symmetric spatial wavefunctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, angular-momentum, wavefunction, baryons

In Griffiths's *Introduction to Elementary Particles* (2nd edition), it is essentially said that the spatial part of the wavefunction of baryons in their ground state is symmetric w.r.t the interchange of quarks because $\ell=\ell'=0$. (Here, $\vec{L}$ is the angular momentum of 1 and 2 about their center of mass, and $\vec{L}'$ is the angular momentum of this combination and three about the center of mass of all three. See Griffiths Fig. 5.12.

But I don't follow this argument at all. Zero angular momentum can tell me whether a state has even or odd parity. How does it tell us anything about whether the spatial wavefunction is symmetric under the interchange of quarks? Can someone prove this or explain it better?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10611/energy-levels-of-3d-isotropic-harmonic-oscillator-nuclear-shell-model). You know that confining potentials like the [3D harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Example:_3D_isotropic_harmonic_oscillator) normally have the [energy increase with $\ell$](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node244.html).... you want a general theorem?

Comment: Are you suggesting that I consider the ground state wavefunction of a system of three noninteracting particles moving in a confining potential (such as the harmonic oscillator) and see what happens?

Comment: Lots of physicists thought that way about the constituent quark model at the time (mid 60s), motivated from nuclear physics. The celebrated Feynman-Kislinger-Ravndal paper (1971)  references some.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are able to ignore higher radial modes due to a large energy separation, there is only one way to get a spatial wavefunction for two particles corresponding to $L_1=L_2=L=0$, which is to have *both* particles in the spherically symmetric $l=0$ state. This $l=0$ state is nondegenerate. Therefore, you must have $$\Psi(r_1,r_2)=\psi_0(r_1)\psi_0(r_2)$$

Where $\psi_0$ is the usual $l=0$ single particle (Hydrogenic) wavefunction.

It is clear that the two particle wavefunction $\Psi(r_1,r_2)$ is symmetric based on particle exchange. This symmetry has more to do with nondegeneracy of $l=0$ than parity per se. As a counterexample, you could not make the same argument if $L=2$ without more information about $m_L$.

This same line of argument applies to $N$ particles, provided it is known that each of them has zero angular momentum $L_i=0$ and the total angular momentum of the collection is $L=0$. Then the multi particle wavefunction is just the product of the $\psi_0(r_i)$ terms.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by uppercase $L$ and lowercase $\ell$? Also, the question was about baryons which are a system of three quarks, not two.

Comment: I tried to use lowercase to denote the single particle wavefunction. From the derivation, the identical argument can be for a system of three particles. The point is that there is only one way to obtain a wavefunction with $L_1=L_2=...=L_3=L=0$

Comment: It’s not true that both particles having L=0 ensures an uncorrelated product state. The radial parts of the two wave functions could be entangled.

Comment: @ragnar yes thank you for that correction. I've added that assumption in.

Comment: @KFGauss This answer does not make the connection to angular momentum. You are assuming a product wave function, based on an approximate energy separation argument. This might be plausible for electrons in an atom, where the nucleus provides an “external” potential, but not for quarks in a hadron.

Comment: If you do have access to higher radial modes, then you *shouldn't* be able to say whether you are in an antisymmetric or symmetric state wrt particle exchange even if they are built to have zero angular momentum. For example, you do have the possibility for an antisymmetric state once you allow $1S$ and $2S$ states. I would think that the statement in Griffiths should have this same basic assumption in the baryon case.

Comment: @KFGauss That’s not correct. Radial mode mixing in the relative coordinate does not affect the exchange symmetry of the wavefunction. A classic example from nuclear physics is the deuteron (proton+neutron), which has total angular momentum J=1, spin S=1 (symmetric under exchange) and positive parity, so the only possible relative orbital angular momenta are L=0,2 which are both symmetric under exchange. So the wavefunction is overall symmetric under exchange, which explains why there is no bound state of two protons or two neutrons. Notice that this argument does not depend on any assumptions

Answer (score 1):

Angular momentum does in fact tell you about parity. Under a parity transformation ($\vec{r}\to -\vec{r}$), the spherical harmonics, which describe orbital angular momentum, get a phase $(-1)^\ell$.

Edit: adding more detail as requested.
A two-particle wave function $\Psi(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2)$ can also be expressed in terms of the relative and center of mass coordinates $\vec{r}=\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2$, $\vec{R}=\vec{r}_1+\vec{r}_2$. Under exchange $1\leftrightarrow 2$, we have $\vec{R} \to \vec{R}$ and $\vec{r} \to -\vec{r}$. (For a bound state, we usually don’t worry about the center of mass coordinate, as it is trivial. The relative orbital angular momentum $\ell$ characterizes the motion described by the relative coordinate $\vec{r}$.)
So under particle exchange, we get a phase factor $(-1)^\ell$. There will also be a phase factor associated with exchanging internal degrees of freedom like spin. So identical spin 1/2 particles in a relative $\ell=0$ state should have a spin singlet to be antisymmetric under exchange.

Second edit:
KFGaus suggests a counterexample, $|S\rangle|D\rangle-|D\rangle|\rangle$. Under parity in the lab frame, this state is unchanged (i.e. it has positive parity) while it gets a minus sign under exchange. When we transform to relative/CM coordinates, the 2 units of angular momentum will be distributed between the relative and CM degrees of freedom in all ways allowed by the applicable symmetries. This includes $|\ell=1,L=1\rangle$ (here $\ell$ is the relative angular momentum and $L$ is the CM angular momentum). The two lab-frame terms $|S\rangle|D\rangle$ and $|D\rangle|S\rangle$ will yield the same breakdown into relative/CM coordinates except with $\vec{r} \to -\vec{r}$, which gives a factor $(-1)^\ell$. All terms with even $\ell$ will cancel in the difference, leaving only odd relative angular momentum. This illustrates a subtlety that I should have been more clear about above. It is the parity under inversion of the relative coordinate (not lab-frame coordinates) that gives the sign under exchange.

Comment: I know that. That's not the question. The question is how does zero angular momentum tell you that the wavefunction is symmetric under the interchange (not parity)?

Comment: If the particles are identical, interchanging the particles and making a parity transformation does the same thing (ignoring internal degrees of freedom like spin).

Comment: @ragner Could you please elaborate or edit your answer to explain this point (with relevant equations maybe)? How is the interchange of particles equivalent to making a parity transformation?

Comment: @ragnar I believe that comment is incorrect and contributes to OP's confusion. Consider the two particle superposition state $\vert \Psi \rangle = \vert S,D\rangle - \vert D,S \rangle$, where $S$ is the s-orbital and $D$ is a d-orbital. This superposition is parity symmetric, but antisymmetric wrt particle exchange.

Comment: Added more detail. Does this help?

Comment: @KFGauss does my updated answer help clarify this point?

Comment: I gave an up vote although I don't see how this answers OPs precise question since "parity in the lab frame" *is* what is mainly meant but parity.